# Comparing negative numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, math

How do you compare negative number in SQL?

What is the equation?

```
  DECLARE @Temperature decimal,
  @Threshold decimal
  Set @Temp = -10  --Degrees
  Set @Threshold = -20  --Degrees

  Select CASE WHEN @Temperature > @Threshold THEN 1 else 0 END
```

I want to write; Select CASE WHEN @Temperature > @Threshold THEN 1 else 0 END

This is easy for positive temperatures.

Comment: it's just as easy for negatives too (hint: it's the same). I don't get what's the problem

Comment: -10 is greater than -20 mathematically speaking.

Comment: That's because it is greater. If that's not what you want, then what exactly it is that you do want?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a (very simple) math related question, not a programming one.

Comment: Case When -20 > -10 Then 1 else 0  --You want this to return 1 because -20 is colder than -10 but -10 is greater than -20, closer to 1.

Comment: Variable declared: `Temp`   Variable Used: `Temperature`   might want to match those up :)

Comment: dude, just use `ABS()`

Comment: @Lamak: ^^ this ... ;)

Comment: Or - if you want to find tempretaures colder than your threshold - simply replace `>` with `<` in your code. `colder == smaller temperature`, `hotter == greater temperature`

Answer (score 0):

Per Lamak I used the ABS() to get the Absolute positive value for the negative comparison.